# Buffer is too large because of CRS

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I'm having an issue in setting the buffer in geopandas. Right now I am trying to set an 805m buffer (roughly 1/2 mile) buffer around an airport.

```
airporturl = 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/1082ad016bc2457ca18451ecc49d1a75_0.geojson'
airport = gp.read_file(airporturl)
airport = airport[airport['COUNTY'] == 'Placer']
airport = airport.to_crs(epsg=4326)
airbuffers['geometry'] = airport.geometry.buffer(805)
```

I get the following warning:

> :1: UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.

and additionally, my buffer is a complete mess (I believe it is in decimal degrees but I'm not entirely sure). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coordinates of your airports are in degrees (longitude/latitude). To build a buffer around entities using planar distance (be it meter or miles) you need first to planify those spheric coordinates first.

This line in your code transforms input coordinates (lat/lon) to lat/lon (4326 stands for lon/lat using a model of the shape of the earth called WGS84). So basically it does nothing.

```
airport = airport.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```

You must use another epsg code that correspond to a planar coordinate system. This is where it begins to be tricky because those systems are not the same depending of where you are (try to flatten a ball !)

You can use the UTM projection family. To find the right one you can use this online tool https://www.latlong.net/lat-long-utm.html

We provide the latitude of Placer (around 39) and longitude (around -121) and it gives the 10S zone. We can now look for the projection "WGS 84 / UTM zone 10S" in https://www.spatialreference.org and get the precious epsg code (which is 32710)

```
airport_utm = airport.to_crs(epsg=32710)
airbuffers['geometry'] = airport_utm.geometry.buffer(805)
```

And there you are now in planar coordinates suitable for the Placer area where you can build your buffer.

If you need lat/lon coordinates for your subsequent code you just have to convert back to 4326.

```
airport = airport_utm.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```

Comment: Cheers! *slaps forehead* That worked perfectly.

Comment: cool. Would you mind accepting my answer then (click on the grey check mark near my answer)